# Elements of a group that send one element to another

Tags: permutation, group-theory

If I have a permutation group, say $S_{10}$, how do I get all the permutations that send the set `{1, 2, 3}` to `{5, 6, 7}`? I know that `GroupOrbits` gives the orbit of a point under the action of the group, but this is somehow the inverse problem

Comment: $S_{10}$ has 3628800 elements, and a not-insignificant fraction of these will map {1,2,3} to {5,6,7}.  You sure you want a list of all of those?  What are you going to do with it?

Comment: You now have seven elements, $\{ 4, \ldots , 10 \}$ that map to seven elements $\{ 1,2,3,4, 8,9, 10\}$, otherwise not constrained.

Comment: These will be the permutations of S7

Comment: Yes, I know that I get 7! permutations that satisfy what I want and, theoretically, I know how to do that, but I wanted to know if Mathematica can do this, not necessarily for this example

Answer (score 0):

```
perms = Select[GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[10]], 
   ContainsExactly[PermutationReplace[{1, 2, 3}, #], {5, 6, 7}] &];
```

Then `perms` is your after. It contains `Length[perms](*30240*)` elements. You can check it:

```
PermutationReplace[{1, 2, 3}, #] & /@ perms
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]